# AWS Cognito OAuth2 access the STATE or SCOPE parameter by some Lambda Trigger

Tags: amazon-cognito, awscognitotoken

When a User is accessing my API and they authenticate through Cognito is it possible to access the STATE of the OAUTH2 AUTH request somehow in one of the lambda triggers?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately as per [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-event-parameter-shared) there is no way to access the `state` parameter in a Cognito trigger. You can however access it in your OAuth2 callback URL, it's passed as a query parameter.